# How to send email and encrypt by google scripts after creating a PDF

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I use this code to create pdf files as soon as a client fills the form:

```
function After_Submit(e){
  
  const info = e.namedValues;
  Create_PDF(info);  
  
  console.log(info);
  

}

function Create_PDF(info) {
  
  const PDF_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder id");
  const TEMP_Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder id");
  const PDF_Template = DriveApp.getFileById("pdf temp id");
  
  const newTempFile = PDF_Template.makeCopy(TEMP_Folder);
  const  OpenDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = OpenDoc.getBody();
  
  console.log(body);
  
   body.replaceText("{Code}", info['Code'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{Date}", info['Date'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{Name}", info['Name'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{Birthdate}", info['Birthdate'][0])
   body.replaceText("{Address}", info['Address'][0]);
   OpenDoc.saveAndClose();
  
  const BLOBPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  PDF_folder.createFile(BLOBPDF).setName(info['Name'][0] + " " + info['Code'][0]);
  console.log("PDF created");
  TEMP_Folder.removeFile(newTempFile);

}
```

obviously I used also triggers to automate it.

Now the I need to make a function that sends that pdf to the email given on the form by the client, and protects it with his birthdate "for example" as a password!

Can anyone help?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) does not have any specific feature or functionality to set passwords in PDF files, for achieving such a thing you will need to use a third party application, API or library.

To send an email with an attachment you can use the method [MailApp.sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) as follows (the following piece of code includes self explanatory comments):

```js
function Create_PDF(info) {
  
  const PDF_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder id");
  const TEMP_Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder id");
  const PDF_Template = DriveApp.getFileById("pdf temp id");
  
  const newTempFile = PDF_Template.makeCopy(TEMP_Folder);
  const  OpenDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = OpenDoc.getBody();
  
  console.log(body);
  
   body.replaceText("{Code}", info['Code'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{Date}", info['Date'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{Name}", info['Name'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{Birthdate}", info['Birthdate'][0])
   body.replaceText("{Address}", info['Address'][0]);
   OpenDoc.saveAndClose();
  
  const BLOBPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  
///////////////////////// MODIFICATION ////////////////////////////////

  // Get the file you want to send as an attachment
  var file = PDF_folder.createFile(BLOBPDF).setName(info['Name'][0] + " " + info['Code'][0]);
  
    // Send email using the function sendEmail of MailApp (recipient, subject, message, options)
    MailApp.sendEmail('mike@example.com', 'Attachment example', 'PDF attached', {
    name: 'Attached file',
    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
    });

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
  console.log("PDF created");
  TEMP_Folder.removeFile(newTempFile);
  
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Glad you got it solved. If my answer solved your question please consider accepting and/or upvoting it. :D

Comment: Unfortunately it gives me this message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Yes, that is for upvoting, however, you can still accept the answer, it is the tick mark on the left side, below the upvote downvote buttons. Thanks for checking it :D